# Why is this javascript function losing closure scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, closures

I'm running this in node.js. Why does the following code segment lose scope for the `cb` var?

```
Client.prototype.post = function(path, data, callback) {
  var self = this;
  var cb = callback;
  return function() {
    console.log(path);
    console.log(cb);
    rest.post(self.baseUrl + path, data).on('complete', cb || this.callback);
  }
};
```

The call to this function looks like this `client.post('/user', {}, function() {});` and outputs the following:

```
/user
undefined
```

I'm expecting the second line to be `[Function]` The returned function is probably being executed with either js's `.call()` or `.apply()` methods to change the scope that it is run in. But I would think that `cb` would be accessible just like `path` is.

**Update:** Wrapping the callback in a function makes it work. But I'd still like an explanation for what's happening here.

```
var cb = function() { callback(); };
```

Comment: `call`/`apply` change the context, not the scope. What you're saying is happening shouldn't be happening, can you link to the actual code?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Squeegy/Uf9nD/ Your problem probably lies elsewhere...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1503056 lines 33-41. The file is used as part of a test suite that uses vowsjs

Comment: That isn't where the issue is, the problem is how you're calling the post function. Where is that code?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. Please update the [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/) to make a representative sample. Note you don't need `cb`; since `callback` is in scope, it will be captured by the closure.

Comment: Just updated the question with that information. See line after the first codeblock

Comment: The call to the function doesn't look like what you posted, otherwise it would work. Post the real code.

Comment: The only explanation is that `callback` is undefined. So you then assign `undefined` to `cb` as well.  But that means you really aren't calling it like you say your are.

Comment: That is the real code. I can't post the line that actually calls the returned anonymous function. That part is buried in vowsjs somewhere. I just tried a simpler test case without vowsjs and it worked like everyone said it would. Looks like its time to dig further.

Comment: The [code sample](http://sscce.org/) is no longer complete, which means the issue still isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected. The question is wrong all the comments are right. Someone needs to learn how to code.